# Could not find a part of the path - ASP.net/C# Image Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, tinymce, umbraco

I have a TinyMCE plugin that I'm using for uploading images using a form. This form works perfectly in FF and Chrome, but breaks in IE8+. I have ensured there is proper permissions to NETWORK SERVICE etc.

Here is the Error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\image.jpg'.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="imgmanager.aspx.cs" Inherits="TinyMCE.NET.tiny_mce.plugins.aspnetbrowser.imgmanager"
    EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/aspnetbrowser.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../tiny_mce_popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/aspnetbrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" action="#">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ImageManagerScriptManager" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorLiteral" runat="server" Text="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:none;">
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="PathSelectLiteral" runat="server" Text="Select Location" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="PathDropDownUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="PathDropDown" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="PathDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--Root--" Value="-1" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!--<asp:Button ID="DeleteFolderButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteFolderButton_Click"
                    OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('do you wish to delete this directory?');" />-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="FolderLiteral" runat="server" Text="Create Folder:" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="FolderTextBox" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="CreateFolderButton" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="CreateFolderButton_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="SelectImageLiteral" runat="server" Text="Select Image:" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageFileUpload" runat="server" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ImageFileUploadRegExValidator" runat="server"
                             ControlToValidate ="ImageFileUpload" ValidationExpression=".*((\.jpg)|(\.bmp)|(\.gif)|(\.png))"
                              ErrorMessage="only jpg, bmp, gif and png files are allowed" Text="*" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Literal ID="AvailableImagesLiteral" runat="server" Text="Available Images:" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ImageGridViewUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PathDropDown" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="ImageGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Name" AllowPaging="true"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="false" OnRowDataBound="imageGridView_RowDataBound"
                            PageSize="5" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ImageGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="ImageGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                            OnRowCommand="ImageGridView_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="ImageGridView_RowDeleting">
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                No Images Found!
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="X" Width="21" Height="21"
                                            ToolTip="delete current image." runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('do you wish to delete this image?');" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Literal ID="radiobuttonMarkup" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Image ID="displayImage" runat="server" style="max-width:200px;" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#cacaca" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="SelectButtonUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageGridView" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Select"
                            OnClientClick="AspNetBrowserDialog.insert(,);return false;" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Cancel"
                    OnClientClick="tinyMCEPopup.close();" />
                 </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace TinyMCE.NET.tiny_mce.plugins.aspnetbrowser
{
    public partial class imgmanager : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        #region variables

        public string host = string.Empty;
        private const string checkedAttributeHTML = "checked=\"checked\"";
        //HACK: the javascript this.style.visibility='hidden'; is a terrible hack to prevent the client doubleclick crash.
        private const string radiobuttonHTML = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"imagegroup\" id=\"selected{0}\" value=\"{0}\" onclick=\"{1};this.style.visibility='hidden';\" {2} />";
        public const string thispage = "imgmanager.aspx";
        public string defaultUploadPath = "~/nForum/uploads/";
        public string aspnetimagebrowserImagePath = string.Empty;
        public string physicalPath = string.Empty;
        public string uploadPath = string.Empty;
        private const string onDeleteError = "File could not be deleted!";
        private const string onFileExistError = "File already exists!";
        private const string onFolderExistError = "Folder already exists!";
        private const string onNoFileSelectedError = "No image file was selected!";
        private const string onFileSaveSuccess = "File was uploaded successfully!";
        private string currentUrl = string.Empty;
        public string aspnetVirtualFolderPath = string.Empty;
        private HttpContext context = null;
        private FileInfo[] imagefiles = new FileInfo[] { };

        #endregion

        #region properties

        private int CurrentIndex 
        {
            get { return (int?) ViewState["CurrentIndex"] ?? -1; }
            set { ViewState["CurrentIndex"] = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            context = HttpContext.Current;
            currentUrl = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            host = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
            if (context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                host = host.Replace("http:/", "https:/");
            }

            physicalPath = context.Server.MapPath("~");
            uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(physicalPath, defaultUploadPath));
            aspnetVirtualFolderPath = ToVirtualPath(context.Request.Path.Replace(thispage, string.Empty));

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SelectButton.Enabled = false;
                BindDirectoryDropDown(); 
            }
            BindData();
        }

        #region binding
        private void BindDirectoryDropDown()
        {
            try
            {
                PathDropDown.Items.Clear();
                PathDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("/images/", uploadPath));
                RecursiveSearch(uploadPath, PathDropDown);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                ErrorLiteral.Text = "UnauthorizedAccessException\n" + ex.Message;
            }
        }

        private DirectoryInfo dirInfo;
        private string parent = string.Empty;

        private void RecursiveSearch(string path, DropDownList dropdown)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                return;
            dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (FileSystemInfo fileInfo in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                if (fileInfo.Attributes == FileAttributes.Directory)
                {
                    parent += "/" + Directory.GetParent(fileInfo.FullName).Name;
                    ListItem li = new ListItem(parent + "/" + fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.FullName);
                    dropdown.Items.Add(li);
                    RecursiveSearch(fileInfo.FullName, dropdown);
                }
            }
            parent = string.Empty;
        }

        #endregion

        protected void PathDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectButton.Enabled = false;
            BindData();
        }

        #region binding

        private void BindData()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(PathDropDown.SelectedValue))
            {
                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(PathDropDown.SelectedValue);
                LoadFiles(info);
            }
        }

        private void LoadFiles(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            var files = info.GetFiles();
            if (files != null)
            {
                imagefiles = files;
                foreach (var item in files)
                {
                    ImageGridView.DataSource = files;
                    ImageGridView.DataBind();
                }

            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IO utilities

        private void DeleteFile(string file)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) && File.Exists(file))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    ErrorLiteral.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        private void DeleteFolder(string folder)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folder) && Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Delete(folder);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorLiteral.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateFolder(string folder)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folder) && !Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                    BindDirectoryDropDown();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorLiteral.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateFile(string file)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) && !File.Exists(file))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorLiteral.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region create/delete directory

        protected void CreateFolderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string folder = FolderTextBox.Text.Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folder))
            {
                string folderPath = Path.Combine(PathDropDown.SelectedValue, folder);
                CreateFolder(folderPath);
                FolderTextBox.Text = "";
            }
        }

        protected void DeleteFolderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string directory = PathDropDown.SelectedValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory) && Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Delete(directory);
                    this.BindDirectoryDropDown();
                    this.BindData();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ErrorLiteral.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region upload file

        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ImageFileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(PathDropDown.SelectedValue))
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile postedFile = ImageFileUpload.PostedFile;
                        postedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(PathDropDown.SelectedValue, postedFile.FileName));
                        ErrorLiteral.Text = onFileSaveSuccess;
                        context.Response.Redirect(currentUrl);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorLiteral.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorLiteral.Text = onNoFileSelectedError;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region gridview methods

        protected void ImageGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ImageGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Delete"))
            {
                var file = imagefiles[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
                if (file != null)
                {
                    DeleteFile(file.FullName);
                    BindData();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void ImageGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void imageGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)e.Row;
                FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)row.DataItem;

                Image imageList = e.Row.FindControl("displayImage") as Image;
                if (imageList != null)
                {
                    imageList.ImageUrl = ToVirtualPath(fi, false);
                }
                Button deleteButton = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteButton") as Button;
                if (deleteButton != null)
                {
                    deleteButton.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(row.RowIndex);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void ImageGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ImageGridView.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                GridViewRow row = ImageGridView.SelectedRow;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    var file = imagefiles[ImageGridView.SelectedIndex];
                    string script = "AspNetBrowserDialog.insert('{0}','{1}');return false;";
                    script = string.Format(script, ToVirtualPath(file, true), file.Name);
                    SelectButton.Enabled = true;
                    SelectButton.OnClientClick = script;
                    CurrentIndex = row.RowIndex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SelectButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region path utilities

        private string ToVirtualPath(FileInfo fi, bool forTinyMCE = false)
        {
            string root = context.Server.MapPath("~/");
            string path = (fi.Directory.FullName + "\\" + fi.Name);
            path = path.Replace(root, string.Empty);
            path = path.Replace("\\", "/");
            if (forTinyMCE)
                return ("/" + path);
            else
                return ("~/" + path);
        }

        private string ToVirtualPath(string filename)
        {
            string root = context.Server.MapPath("~/");
            string path = filename;
            path = path.Replace(root, string.Empty);
            path = path.Replace("\\", "/");
            return ("~/" + path);
        }

        #endregion

        #region render

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            foreach(GridViewRow row in ImageGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    Literal radiobuttonMarkup = row.FindControl("radiobuttonMarkup") as Literal;
                    if (radiobuttonMarkup != null)
                    {
                        string script = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ImageGridView, "Select$" + row.RowIndex, true);
                        string attr = string.Empty;
                        if (CurrentIndex == row.RowIndex)
                            attr = checkedAttributeHTML;
                        radiobuttonMarkup.Text = string.Format(radiobuttonHTML, row.RowIndex, script, attr);
                    }
                }
            }
            base.Render(writer);
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the client side code where you are uploading the files. the problem does not seem to be on the server side

Comment: I've added the aspx file and also can clarify that the "defaultUploadPath" value is correct.

Comment: That is a browser/client-side problem. That full file path does not make it to the server (for security reasons).

Comment: I know there is an option in IE "include local directory path when uploading files to a server" that when you disable, it fixes the upload issue. My concern is that this is an intranet system and I don't want it to affect other systems if I disable this feature. Is there any kind of work around, server side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by changing:

```
HttpPostedFile postedFile = ImageFileUpload.PostedFile;
postedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(PathDropDown.SelectedValue, postedFile.FileName));
```

to:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(ImageFileUpload.FileName);
ImageFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/nForum/uploads/") + filename);
```